# conditional statement does not work even if the statement returns true for image captions

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to write a conditional if statement to get image caption if number of images match number of captions in the db row

code does work without if statement but fails to execute even if the condition returns true.

```
php  

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $individual_files = explode("|", $row["images_names"]);
            $individual_text = explode("_", $row["image_text"]);
            for ($file_number = 0; $file_number < sizeof($individual_files) - 1; $file_number++) {
               if( count($individual_files)  == count($individual_text)) {
                        echo "<li>";
                        echo "<img src='Blog-Albums/" . $row["sno"] . "/" . $individual_files[$file_number] . "' alt='gallery image'/>";
                        echo "<div class='slider-caption'><p style='color:#ffffff'>this is sample file</p></div>";
                        echo "</li>";

                } elseif ( count($individual_files)  != count($individual_text)) {
                               echo "<li><img src='Blog-Albums/" . $row["sno"] ."/". $individual_files[$file_number] . "' alt='gallery image'/><div class='slider-caption'><p></p></div></li>";
                }
```

Comment: use `if(count($individual_files) == count($individual_text)) {` as well as i have no idea why you applied `for()` loop before `if()`. Please explain. Seems like it also have some influence on `if-else` block.

Comment: the `if-else` condition is not depending on the iteration variable. So either it will be true for all iterations, either it will be false for all iterations. So, either the loop should be inside the `if-else`, either the loop condition is wrong. I would go for the second one. And, more to that, you should put the `ìf-else` only on the content of the slider-caption `div`. The rest of the code is identical for both branches

Comment: I have usef for() loop because even if the statement returns true or false I want the $file_number to continue.

Comment: @peacewalker  i am agreed with Wisthler. either loop needs to be removed or need to be inside `if-else`

Comment: i have added another for statement for $individual_text number inside if statement and that did fix the issue.